# JS-zIndex: Can't change z-index of element dynamically

Tags: javascript, popup, z-index

...for chrome extension
I have couple of popups, and I want to bring clicked one on top

[screenshot](http://prntscr.com/2vesxc)

this is what I did

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", function test(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    if (evt.target.className == 'popup') {
        //evt.target.style.backgroundColor = "blue";  **** successful test
        zIndex++;
        evt.target.style.zIndex = zIndex;
        evt.target.innerHTML = zIndex;
        console.log(evt.target.style.zIndex);
    }


});
```

on every click (on popup class) there is a counter that raise z-index by 1, save it to variable zIndex, and then that variable is applied to clicked element through

```
evt.target.style.zIndex = zIndex;
```

counter works, innerHTML is set to show z-index (`evt.target.innerHTML = zIndex;`)
and also console is showing z-index of clicked element(popup)

but....that popup is not coming in front

What am I missing?

tnx

Comment: You should "right click" > "inspect element" the popup and check its z-index in the style tab. Good luck !

Comment: @olivieradam666 yes it is

Comment: can you please provide jsfiddle?

Comment: Could you provide a jsFiddle to help us narrow the problem area? My guess is that some of the elements have `position:static`, but without more information, it is just a guess. I assume the problem can be reproduced outside of the chrome extension context.

Comment: I have a bck script for context menu that triggers popup...don't know how to insert it into jsfiddle

Comment: and no, I dont have position: static elements

Comment: Perhaps a working example (with your exact code) will help you identify the problem: http://jsbin.com/velaj/1/edit

Comment: OMG...
I did stupid mistake....
I've added one **0** too much in *zIndex* variable that was used for counter
10000000000 instead of
1000000000
 (max is 2147483647)...and ofc...all popups were on same layer
.
Thank you all for comments and examples.
...this bug was driving me crazy, cause I know I did everything correct
well...not everything :-)
and apologies for time waste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create 2 CSS classes, one called focus and one called unfocus.  When you click on your element, you should swap the class.  The currently clicked element will get the focus class with a high static z-index.  The last clicked element, that was focused will get swapped back to unfocus with the low static z-index.  I'll post some code as quickly as I can whip it up, but this is the method you should be using instead of stepping zIndex up incrementally.

Here is a basic example, simply replace my color background with your z-index settings.

```
<html><head><title></title>
<style>
  .first{
    background:silver;
    padding:20px;
    color:#ffffff;
    z-index:9000;
  }
  .second{
    background:yellow;
    padding:30px;
    color:#000000;
    z-index:9001;
  }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var y;  // create a variable to save the last focused element.
  function changeClass(x) {
    if (y) {
        y.className="first"; // sets last focused element to original style
    }
    x.className="second";  // sets current focused element to new style
    y = x;  // sets current element as y (the basis of a toggle)
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div1" class="first" style="width: 200px;" onclick="changeClass(this);">Click me and I will change!</div>
    <div id="div2" class="first" style="width: 200px;" onclick="changeClass(this);">Click me and I will change too!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is this in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v55z7/

Comment: Why should the OP use your method? What is the problem with the method the OP uses that is fixed by your solution?

Comment: because the OP method is simply wrong, my method is a common toggle method for window handling and is more efficient and practical. Eventually the OP will run out of z-index space the more and more a window gets clicked, granted its a high number, 9999 i believe, but still, why support bad javascript.

Comment: I wasn't contesting your answer, i'm just asking common sense questions that your answer should probably answer. Simply giving the solution is ok, but explaining why the solution works is a lot better.

Comment: I have to change a lots of code to implement class switch :)

Comment: @Tibos agreed.. i'm just trying to figure out how to explain why toggling a class is the proper method, it seems like such a basic fundamental to me that I can't see how to put in laymens terms.

Comment: @vux777 - you shouldn't need to change much.. add a variable to store the last clicked window. Change your event listener to swap the classes.. then add two simple styles into your stylesheet. A 5 minute fix tops.  Trust me it will be worth it, you'll now have a very nice dynamic window system for re-use in many ways.

Comment: thanx for effort...I solved it... my last comment under my question...thanx

Answer (score 0):

z-index is relative to the other objects on screen.

If you increment z-index for an element you need to relativly decrease the bottom element

Comment: can you provide more info. If I have multiple popups, do I need to decres all of them or...?

Comment: Say you have 3 divs. each have a z-index when the default value is 0. 
consider it as counters, when the largest one is on top. 
so if you increment the z-index for elemnt1 and its now 10 but the z-index for elment2 is 11 elemnt2 will still be on top

Comment: nope...lower popups had smaller z-index than upper popups (checked in devtools)...I solved in the meantime...comment under my question...thanx anyway